# Прямая речь.Задание

Tags: прямая-речь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой ответ: 1.
...................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно.

*Валя сказала, **что** она будет ждать её (его) где-нибудь поблизости.*